# python lxml get the name of a node

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

This is my xml file:

```
<FuzzyComparison>
    <Modules>
        <Module>
            <name>AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule</name>
            <configurationLoader>DefaultLoader</configurationLoader>
            <configurationFile>MakesModels.conf</configurationFile>
            <settings></settings>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <name>DefaultFuzzyComparisonModule</name>
            <configurationLoader>DefaultLoader</configurationLoader>
            <configurationFile>Buildings.conf</configurationFile>
            <settings>
                <attribute>building</attribute>
            </settings>
        </Module>
    </Modules>
    </FuzzyComparison>
```

This is the code I've been trying to parse it with:

```
from lxml import etree
class AttributesXMLParser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.doc=etree.parse('Items.xml')

    def getValueOfTag(self, tagName): #This function returns the value of a specific tag for exmaple, the tageName could be "FirstDate"
        return self.doc.find(tagName).text

    def loadFuzzySettings(self):
        modulesDict = list()
        modules = self.doc.findall('FuzzyComparison/Modules/Module')
        for module in modules:
            moduleDict = dict()
            moduleName = module.find('name').text
            moduleDict['name'] = moduleName
            moduleConfigurationLoader = module.find('configurationLoader').text
            moduleDict['configurationLoader'] = moduleConfigurationLoader
            moduleConfigurationFile = module.find('configurationFile').text
            moduleDict['moduleConfigurationFile'] = moduleConfigurationFile
            settings = module.findall('settings')
            settingsDict = dict()
            for oneSetting in settings:
                settingsDict[oneSetting] = oneSetting.text
            moduleDict['settings'] = settingsDict
            modulesDict.append(moduleDict)
        return modulesDict
```

and this is the results:

```
[{'moduleConfigurationFile': 'MakesModels.conf', 'configurationLoader': 'Default
Loader', 'name': 'AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule', 'settings': {<Element
 settings at 0x25257c8>: None}}, {'moduleConfigurationFile': 'Buildings.conf', '
configurationLoader': 'DefaultLoader', 'name': 'DefaultFuzzyComparisonModule', '
settings': {<Element settings at 0x2525e48>: '\n\t\t\t\t'}}]
```

#### My problem

I don't know how to get the name and value of the `settings` node, because as you see everything is working great except the `settings`, I need to have it like this:

```
"attribute": building
```

But my code gives me:

```
{<Element settings at 0x2525e48>: '\n\t\t\t\t'}}]
```

Could you help please to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `findall()` returns a list, you want to iterate over the contents of elements of that list, rather than the list itself.  You also want to use the element's tag as a key, rather than using the element itself.

```
settingsDict = {}
for settingsNode in module.findall('settings'):
    for setting in settingsNode:
        settingsDict[setting.tag] = setting.text
```

Or, if you only have one `settings` tag,

```
settingsDict = {}
for setting in module.find('settings'):
    settingsDict[setting.tag] = setting.text
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
settingsDict = {setting.tag: setting.text
                for setting in module.find('settings')}
```

Comment: I will just have one `settings` tag, which will have many values, is there any way to avoid doing `findall` on the `settings` tag please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli:Then why did the code use `module.findall()` in the first place?  I've noticed that the code uses `module.find()` elsewhere.

Comment: It was my mistake, however, i tried now to use just find and use just one loop (instead of two) but now i am getting empty results in the settings, nothing is being saved

Comment: you can try the code yourself, it is a working code, you just need to run it

Comment: I can't in fact try the code myself, because you changed the code and haven't posted the changes.  But I have updated the answer.

Comment: it is working, it was my mistake also, i puted the .tag in the dictionary not in the key, thank you now working great